# WMI releases my implementation of IWbemQuerySink too many times (ExecQueryAsync): refcount turns negative

Tags: winapi, rust, com, wmi

I've implemented the IWbemQuerySink in rust, in order to use ExecQueryAsync. Code is available [in this pull request](https://github.com/ohadravid/wmi-rs/pull/30) but I'll post the relevant bits here.

**TLDR;**

WMI is calling Release() 5 times on my QuerySink implementation, 1 which is understandable, and 4 which are not... There is only 1 call to AddRef by WMI, so the question is: where do this 4 other calls to Release comes from and is there a way to prevent them from happening?

**With a lot of details**

Here is a simplified implementation, it is working great:

```rust
use winapi::{
    um::wbemcli::{
        {IWbemClassObject,IWbemObjectSink, IWbemObjectSinkVtbl},
        WBEM_S_NO_ERROR,
    },
    shared::{
        ntdef::HRESULT,
        wtypes::BSTR,
    },
    ctypes::{
        c_long,
    },
};
use com_impl::{ComImpl, VTable, Refcount};
use wio::com::ComPtr;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(ComImpl)]
#[interfaces(IWbemObjectSink)]
pub struct QuerySink {
    vtbl: VTable<IWbemObjectSinkVtbl>,
    refcount: Refcount,
}

impl QuerySink {
    pub fn new() -> ComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> {
        let ptr = QuerySink::create_raw();
        let ptr = ptr as *mut IWbemObjectSink;
        unsafe { ComPtr::from_raw(ptr) }
    }
}

// AddRef and Release methods are provided by com_impl
#[com_impl::com_impl]
unsafe impl IWbemObjectSink for QuerySink {
    pub unsafe fn indicate(
        &self,
        _lObjectCount: c_long,
        _apObjArray: *mut *mut IWbemClassObject
    ) -> HRESULT {
        WBEM_S_NO_ERROR as i32
    }

    pub unsafe fn set_status(
        &self,
        _lFlags: c_long,
        _hResult: HRESULT,
        _strParam: BSTR,
        _pObjParam: *mut IWbemClassObject
    ) -> HRESULT {
        WBEM_S_NO_ERROR as i32
    }
}
```

Let's try to use it in a simple call to ExecQueryAsync:

```rust
pub fn exec_async_query_native_wrapper(
        &self,
        query: impl AsRef<str>,
    ) -> Result<(), WMIError> {
        let query_language = BStr::from_str("WQL")?;
        let query = BStr::from_str(query.as_ref())?;

        let p_sink: ComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> = QuerySink::new();

        unsafe {
            check_hres((*self.svc()).ExecQueryAsync(
                query_language.as_bstr(),
                query.as_bstr(),
                WBEM_FLAG_BIDIRECTIONAL as i32,
                ptr::null_mut(),
                p_sink.as_raw(),
            ))?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
```

When executing it in a test, this code panics because the release function is called too many times, and the Refcount becomes negative:

```
attempt to subtract with overflow', C:\Users\apennamen\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\com-impl-0.1.1\src\lib.rs:139:9
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/b32e6e6ac8921035177256ab6806e6ab0d4b9b94\/library\std\src\panicking.rs:493
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/b32e6e6ac8921035177256ab6806e6ab0d4b9b94\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:92
   2: core::panicking::panic
             at /rustc/b32e6e6ac8921035177256ab6806e6ab0d4b9b94\/library\core\src\panicking.rs:50
   3: com_impl::Refcount::release
             at C:\Users\apennamen\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\com-impl-0.1.1\src\lib.rs:139
   4: wmi::query_sink::QuerySink::__com_impl__IUnknown__Release
             at .\src\query_sink.rs:31
   5: CoMarshalInterface
   6: CoMarshalInterface
.....
```

After some tests, I found that the Release method is called 4 times more than it should be by WMI. So when adding 4 calls to AddRef, the code works just fine. This is of course not satisfying as maybe tomorrow it will be 5 calls, or 10 or 2...
I don't know how to handle this problem, hopefully someone else ran into it

This is a hacky working code:

```rust
pub fn exec_async_query_native_wrapper(
        &self,
        query: impl AsRef<str>,
    ) -> Result<(), WMIError> {
        let query_language = BStr::from_str("WQL")?;
        let query = BStr::from_str(query.as_ref())?;

        let p_sink: ComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> = QuerySink::new();

        unsafe {
            // FIXME hack the RefCount
            for _ in 0..4 { p_sink.AddRef(); }

            check_hres((*self.svc()).ExecQueryAsync(
                query_language.as_bstr(),
                query.as_bstr(),
                WBEM_FLAG_BIDIRECTIONAL as i32,
                ptr::null_mut(),
                p_sink.as_raw(),
            ))?;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading this far :)

EDIT :
Here is the expanded macro code:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "async-query")]
pub(crate) mod query_sink {
    use winapi::{
        um::wbemcli::{
            {IWbemClassObject, IWbemObjectSink, IWbemObjectSinkVtbl}, WBEM_S_NO_ERROR,
            WBEM_STATUS_COMPLETE,
        },
        shared::{
            ntdef::HRESULT,
            wtypes::BSTR,
            winerror::{E_POINTER, E_FAIL},
        },
        ctypes::{c_long},
    };
    use com_impl::{ComImpl, VTable, Refcount};
    use log::{trace, warn};
    use std::ptr::NonNull;
    use wio::com::ComPtr;
    use crate::result_enumerator::IWbemClassWrapper;
    use crate::WMIError;
    /// Implementation for [IWbemObjectSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wbemcli/nn-wbemcli-iwbemobjectsink).
    /// This [Sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sink_(computing))
    /// receives asynchronously the result of the query,
    /// through Indicate calls. When finished,the SetStatus method
    /// is called.
    /// # <https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/wmisdk/example--getting-wmi-data-from-the-local-computer-asynchronously>
    #[repr(C)]
    #[interfaces(IWbemObjectSink)]
    pub struct QuerySink {
        vtbl: VTable<IWbemObjectSinkVtbl>,
        refcount: Refcount,
    }
    impl QuerySink {
        fn create_raw() -> *mut Self {
            Box::into_raw(Box::new(QuerySink {
                vtbl: <Self as com_impl::BuildVTable<_>>::static_vtable(),
                refcount: Default::default(),
            }))
        }
    }
    unsafe impl com_impl::BuildVTable<winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknownVtbl> for QuerySink {
        const VTBL: winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknownVtbl = winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknownVtbl {
            AddRef: Self::__com_impl__IUnknown__AddRef,
            Release: Self::__com_impl__IUnknown__Release,
            QueryInterface: Self::__com_impl__IUnknown__QueryInterface,
        };
        fn static_vtable() -> com_impl::VTable<winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknownVtbl> {
            com_impl::VTable::new(&Self::VTBL)
        }
    }
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    impl QuerySink {
        #[inline(never)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl__IUnknown__AddRef(
            this: *mut winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknown,
        ) -> u32 {
            let this = &*(this as *const Self);
            this.refcount.add_ref()
        }
        #[inline(never)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl__IUnknown__Release(
            this: *mut winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknown,
        ) -> u32 {
            let ptr = this as *mut Self;
            let count = (*ptr).refcount.release();
            if count == 0 {
                Box::from_raw(ptr);
            }
            count
        }
        #[inline(never)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl__IUnknown__QueryInterface(
            this: *mut winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknown,
            riid: *const winapi::shared::guiddef::IID,
            ppv: *mut *mut winapi::ctypes::c_void,
        ) -> winapi::shared::winerror::HRESULT {
            if ppv.is_null() {
                return winapi::shared::winerror::E_POINTER;
            }
            if winapi::shared::guiddef::IsEqualIID(
                &*riid,
                &<winapi::um::unknwnbase::IUnknown as winapi::Interface>::uuidof(),
            ) || winapi::shared::guiddef::IsEqualIID(
                &*riid,
                &<IWbemObjectSink as winapi::Interface>::uuidof(),
            ) {
                *ppv = this as *mut winapi::ctypes::c_void;
                winapi::shared::winerror::S_OK
            } else {
                *ppv = std::ptr::null_mut();
                winapi::shared::winerror::E_NOINTERFACE
            }
        }
    }
    impl QuerySink {
        pub fn new() -> ComPtr<IWbemObjectSink> {
            let ptr = QuerySink::create_raw();
            let ptr = ptr as *mut IWbemObjectSink;
            unsafe { ComPtr::from_raw(ptr) }
        }
    }
    unsafe impl com_impl::BuildVTable<IWbemObjectSinkVtbl> for QuerySink {
        const VTBL: IWbemObjectSinkVtbl = IWbemObjectSinkVtbl {
            parent: <Self as com_impl::BuildVTable<_>>::VTBL,
            Indicate: Self::__com_impl_stub__IWbemObjectSink__Indicate,
            SetStatus: Self::__com_impl_stub__IWbemObjectSink__SetStatus,
        };
        fn static_vtable() -> com_impl::VTable<IWbemObjectSinkVtbl> {
            com_impl::VTable::new(&Self::VTBL)
        }
    }
    #[allow(non_snake_case)]
    impl QuerySink {
        #[inline(never)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl_stub__IWbemObjectSink__Indicate(
            this: *mut IWbemObjectSink,
            __com_arg_0: c_long,
            __com_arg_1: *mut *mut IWbemClassObject,
        ) -> HRESULT {
            let this = &*(this as *const Self);
            Self::__com_impl_body__IWbemObjectSink__Indicate(this, __com_arg_0, __com_arg_1)
        }
        #[inline(never)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl_stub__IWbemObjectSink__SetStatus(
            this: *mut IWbemObjectSink,
            __com_arg_0: c_long,
            __com_arg_1: HRESULT,
            __com_arg_2: BSTR,
            __com_arg_3: *mut IWbemClassObject,
        ) -> HRESULT {
            let this = &*(this as *const Self);
            Self::__com_impl_body__IWbemObjectSink__SetStatus(
                this,
                __com_arg_0,
                __com_arg_1,
                __com_arg_2,
                __com_arg_3,
            )
        }
        #[inline(always)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl_body__IWbemObjectSink__Indicate(
            &self,
            lObjectCount: c_long,
            apObjArray: *mut *mut IWbemClassObject,
        ) -> HRESULT {
            WBEM_S_NO_ERROR as i32
        }
        #[inline(always)]
        unsafe extern "system" fn __com_impl_body__IWbemObjectSink__SetStatus(
            &self,
            lFlags: c_long,
            _hResult: HRESULT,
            _strParam: BSTR,
            _pObjParam: *mut IWbemClassObject,
        ) -> HRESULT {
            WBEM_S_NO_ERROR as i32
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's at least one `Release()` call from the [ComPtr::drop()](https://github.com/retep998/wio-rs/blob/9bf021178b2d02485f1bd35e6cff41bf52d4a9a2/src/com.rs#L120) implementation. And the backtrace seems to indicate that `com_impl` does its own reference counting on top of that. Have you verified that `ComPtr` and `com_impl` are compatible with each other?

Comment: Hello @IInspectable thanks for your answer, yes I checked on my side and yes those two libraries are compatible. You can see here https://docs.rs/com-impl/0.1.1/com_impl/ in the example that it uses wio::com::ComPtr 
I think both maintainer of each library contribute to each others, and they were "made" to work together.
com_impl initialize the RefCount to 1, so no need to explicitly call AddRef, and ComPtr handles the Release so no need to explicitly call it. I can provide the 4 StackTraces (one after addin AddRef), they all point to WMI classes when panicking

Comment: What's `self` in `exec_async_query_native_wrapper`. More specifically, what does `check_hres((*self.svc())` return? Is this maybe a temporary? It would also help to see the complete source code after macro expansion.

Comment: `(*self.svc()) `refers to a WMIConnection, the full code is available here: https://github.com/ohadravid/wmi-rs/pull/30
`check_hres` check the result of ExecQueryAsync, not of `*self.svc`, it's similar to HRESULT macro in Winapi if I understand correctly. Which macro particularly you'd like to see expanded ? The com_impl macro ? I made a version of the code where I implemented AddRef and Release myself, using the same code as the com_impl macro, to add `println!` statements. I see one call made to AddRef and 4 calls to Release that doesn't come from me

Comment: Hello, just to provide some info @IInspectable, there might be an issue with com-impl (no call to AddRef in QueryInterface), which should be fixed soon and  therefore close my problem. So don't spend anymore time on this issue ;) Thanks a lot for looking into it, I'll provide an answer to the question when I'll be sure everything is correct.

Comment: The macro-expanded source code for the interface implementation would have given that away. And yes, the `QueryInterface` implementation is wrong (and that's not the only bug). In all, the *com_impl* crate doesn't look entirely trustworthy.

Comment: I'll follow your advice and try the [cargo-expand macro](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand). I'm interested if you spotted some suspicious parts in _com_impl_ because it is the only crate I found to provide the functionnalities I need, and I think I would have done much worse trying to implement it myself... The _com_impl_ was at least review a bit as it is mentionned in [this MSRC blog post](https://msrc-blog.microsoft.com/2019/10/08/designing-a-com-library-for-rust/), so it provides a bit more guarantee than just myself :)

Comment: QuerySink does not look good.  You must call AddRef() when you return an interface pointer, the client code calls Release when it is done with it.  The semantics of ComPtr in Rust are not obvious to me, but if it is similar to the smart pointer class in C++ then it cannot safely wrap the returned pointer, its destructor would return the pointer with the reference count at 0.

Comment: Hello @HansPassant, indeed AddRef was missing, a PR was accepted. to fix this issue. For ComPtr you refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/com-coding-practices#com-smart-pointers ?
Currently, it is implemented in the Drop trait https://github.com/retep998/wio-rs/blob/master/src/com.rs#L122